# AngularJS - disable some routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As title already suggests, I'm trying to disable some routes. I'm using angular seed project, that already has a nice structure.

I'm using JWT and I'm trying to set up a structure where if a certain route requires user to be logged in, and the user is not logged in, it redirects him to the some other page.

On my `angular.module` I've added the following code:

```
.run(['$rootScope', 'userService', '$location', function($rootScope, userService, $location) {

    userService.init();

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {

        $rootScope.isPrivate = next['authenticate'];
        if ($rootScope.isPrivate) {
            if (!userService.get())
                $location.path('/');
        }

    });
}]);
```

And this is a protected route:

```
angular.module('myApp.view2', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/admin/vnos-stevilke', {
        templateUrl: 'view2/view2.html',
        controller: 'View2Ctrl',
        authenticate: true
    }).when('/admin/vnos-stevilke/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'view2/view2.html',
        controller: 'View2Ctrl',
        authenticate: true
    });
}])

.controller('View2Ctrl', ['$scope', 'webServices', '$location', '$routeParams', function($scope, webServices, $location, $routeParams) {

    if ($routeParams.id)
        webServices.getBranchById($routeParams.id, function(err, data) {
            $scope.branch = data;
        });

    webServices.getCompanies(function(err, data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log('no access!');
        if (!err)
            $scope.companies = data;
    });

}]);
```

now at first it appears to be working OK: if I'm not logged in, the route is not displayed and I get redirected back to the root. But at a closer look I've noticed that `console.log('no access!');` is still displayed in the console. So it appears that controller gets initialized.

It seems like the whole route is loaded and then gets redirected if user is not logged in. That is not the behaviour I'm looking for. I'm trying to HOLD the loading of the route until I'm sure the user is logged in.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I changed the code accordingly with the suggestion below, but it doesn't seem to work. Where have I gone wrong?

userService method that checks if user is logged in:

```
this.isLogged = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (current === null) return deferred.reject();
    else return deferred.resolve(current);
};
```

Run method:

```
.run(['$rootScope', 'userService', '$location', function($rootScope, userService, $location) {

    userService.init();

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function() {
        $location.path('/');
    });
}]);
```

Restricted page:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/admin/vnos-stevilke', {
        templateUrl: 'view2/view2.html',
        controller: 'View2Ctrl',
        resolve: function(userService) {
            console.log('test');
            return userService.isLogged();
        }
    });
}])
```

Here, the "test" never displays in console.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just decide if you are letting user into restricted area with `resolve` route parameter.
If in one of resolve function resolves with a promise object that is rejected it stops entering requested route.

I would write something like:

```
$routeProvider.when('/restrictedURL',{
    ...some params,
    resolve: function(userService){
        return userService.get();   
    }
}
```

...and make userService.get return a Promise object that is resolved if session is active and rejected otherwise.

Now.. if promise is rejected a **route won't be launched** and  [$routeChangeError](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#$routeChangeError) event is raised, so you need something like:

```
angular.module('yourapp').run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError",function(){
         $location.path('/');
    });
});
```

read more about resolve parameter @ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: I can't seem to get this working. I've updated my question with your solution, but it doesn't seem to be working